# What does it mean for a variable to be statistically significant but not selected as important by classification methods?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, feature-selection, lasso, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm basically playing around with some lipidomics data to practice, so my question is purely theoretical.

I wanted to see if I could find lipid classes that differ between two groups and I was comparing the results. When I use hypothesis tests (parametric and non-parametric) I consistently find one lipid class that is significantly altered after adjusting for multiple comparisons. However, when I run other types of analyses like Naive Bayes, random forest, and LASSO (as multiresponse Gaussian regression) I get very low accuracy and the important variables are completely different.

The data looks like this:

[image]

The x-axes represent log2-transformed total concentration per lipid class. LPE is the class that keeps coming up as significantly altered, but not important to classification methods.

Could these results indicate that the hypothesis tests are innappropriate for this data?

Comment: It's hard to know for sure, but I think one possiblity is that you were overfitting your data.  A full answer might require that some expert have access to your full dataset.

Comment: Do you mean that you're running 15 t-tests of these log2 lipid values between patients and controls & (only) 1 is significant after controlling for multiple comparisons, and then you are using these variables as predictors of group membership in machine learning classifiers?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which one was significant before & which ones are selected by the classifiers?  Do you get the same set for all the different types of classifiers?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica First comment: yes, I did 15 testsand also tried one MANOVA with all the variables.  I got LPE as significant on Mann-Whitney and O-PE in a permutation test and MANOVA.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica The classifiers just can't manage to separate the controls when I try the test set, but they consider C24 Bile acids, O-PE, and some others more important than LPE. Also I tried LASSO and that one just chose half the variables as important (not LPE)

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of proteins classes like carnitines, acyl carnitines, saturated & unsaturated fats for patients seem to sit right on top of those for controls, meaning that their mode and/or median looks very close between the two groups.  During class prediction (classification analysis), some classifiers require different central tendencies between feature values in classes in order to be informative with greater performance.  A groupwise difference (pattern) of the LPE protein class is commonly what classifiers need in order to pickup good separation between values among the classes.  Log-transforms probably won't help with e.g. carnitines, acyl carnitines, saturated & unsaturated fats.  Most likely any classifier would perform reasonably well for LPE proteins.

Overall, for your data, I only see C24-Bile acids, Hode, O-PE, LPE, and PE with different modes (location of major "hump") between groups.  Everything else presents a less drastic difference between the location (expression value) where the major hump lies.  In this case, "hump" is the mode, the most frequently occurring expression value.

Sometimes it also helps to look at the patterns or clusters in data using unsupervised methods before performing supervised class prediction.  For example, the panel below shows the major cluster groupings of 178 wines in 3 classes from the Wine dataset UCI (U-Cal, Irvine) Machine Learning Repository, based on inputting all 13 features into each unsupervide method. The actual X-Y values in a particular plot that shows good separation between objects in the different classes (colors) can then be input into a classifier.  Doing this would merely be called "transforming protein expression values using linear/non-linear manifold learning methods", where you would input values of all 15 of your proteins into the unsupervised method and return a new set of 2 or 3 variables (reduced dimensions), which would be used for 2D or 3D plots.

[image]

Comment: I worry that using dimensionality reduction methods like those would make it impossible  for me to tell which specific lipid classes were important later on.

Comment: There are ways to determine the contribution of original proteins to the impact of the reduced dimensions on classification results.  You could start by avoiding Chol esters, LPC, O-PC, SM, PC, since their expression in controls is essentially noise.